# Worklight changing permissions in android manifest

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I have a hybrid worklight application that is building for Android.  I need to do push notifications, and the permissions are in the manifest file.  By default, it is using the incorrect package name for the permission, so push notifications fail.  I change the manifest file in the worklight android environment, but if I make some changes to the app and need to rebuild the android environment, it will change the permissions back to the incorrect value.  It only does this for the push permissions, it does not change it any other place.

The package name is com.bcbst.mma, but whenever it builds the android app, it changes it to com.mma.  Where in the build process would it be changing the package name to an incorrect value?  The application descriptor file contains the correct package name, so I don't know where it would be getting the incorrect value from.

EDIT:
This is what the permissions look like in the manifest file

```
<permission android:name="com.mma.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>  
<uses-permission android:name="com.mma.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>
```

This is what I want:

```
<permission android:name="com.bcbst.mma.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>  
<uses-permission android:name="com.bcbst.mma.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>
```

When I do a build, it changes it back to the first listing.  I tried what @DJones suggested and it worked as I want, but if that is no longer the recommended method, how do I prevent that from happening again?

Comment: Are you doing your changing in the generated Android project or in the your-app\android\native folder? You should do your changes in the latter and not in the former. The androidmanifest.xml file is considered a 'user file' and should not be altered by the Worklight builder after it has been generated for you for the first time.

Comment: I am also interested in hearing more about the failure - why would it fail for you by changing the package name? Does the sample push notification fail for you as well...?

Comment: I change it in the native folder, but when I do a build, it reverts it back to the wrong name for the permission. The sample app does work, and our app works if I change the manifest file after I build the app, but if I do not modify it before I try to use the app, on startup of the app it will say it push services are not available, and the message says it is missing a permission.

Comment: if the nativeResources folder helps you - you can continue using it. The folder is not going anywhere any time soon.

Comment: I've also created a new application and updated the package name in the same permission line and on build time it stayed the same -- it did not revert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In worklight 6.2 android environment structure has a "***native***" and a "***nativeResources***" folder. 
[image]

Try making all your changes in the *nativeResources* folder. When you add your changes to the ***nativeResources*** directory, it is copied to the native directory during the build.

Comment: We no longer recommend this approach; additionally, per my comments there is no reason to put there the AndroidManifest.xml file because it is considered a user file, a file that Worklight should not override.

Comment: However, if it works for you - you Should use it. This folder is not going anywhere anytime soon.

Comment: @IdanAdar Maybe your suggestion of changing the file in the "native" folder would work if the same file  is deleted from the "nativeResources" folder. That way the WL build procedure would have no files to replace the existing one. Maybe worth a try if "nativeResources" directory isn't recommended.